# shouldn't this edit be a rejected edit in the end?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

see the following edit on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4443218

There review edit log was relatively controversial, but it got finally approved:

```
Approved 13 mins ago:
Ayush reviewed this 13 mins ago: Approve
samanime reviewed this 14 mins ago: Reject
This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.
Rolando Isidoro reviewed this 20 mins ago: Approve
Adi Inbar reviewed this 20 mins ago: Reject
This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.
conor reviewed this 21 mins ago: Approve
```

The edit does do some nice formatting, but it also cuts some code.
In my opinion should be clearly rejected since relevant code got cut. But well, I am relatively new at stackoverflow... maybe I missunderstood something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edit was approved because three of the five reviewers approved. The process is democratic, and *should* be subjective/qualitative, but unfortunately we have a lot of robo-reviewers in the system who care a lot more about rep/badges than quality.

Thankfully, edits that ultimately get approved but shouldn't, can still be rolled back (or important information that has been stripped can be edited back in). I personally don't know enough about the technology to be sure that is appropriate in this case, since I don't know if the removed code was relevant or noise.

Taking you at your word that that part of the code is relevant, I've rolled the edit back, and left [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701266/android-logcat-shows-error-on-setonclicklistener#comment34591466_22701266):

> @Onik if you want to improve the formatting, please do so without stripping potentially relevant code.

Comment: Ok, I understand the democratic review system. About the stripped code: yes it was highly relevant. (I requested this code in my comment and turns out the bug is in the code). I'd vote for a rollback. (Or democracy ends here already :-P ? )

Comment: Even if the code would not have been relevant: It should not have been stripped either in my opinion. It would still have been an invalid edit because of `radical change`? Or more generally speaking: should there ever be stripped code from a question?

Comment: @donfuxx I have stripped irrelevant code from both questions and answers by other people, so no, I disagree with you that edits should be rejected as too radical simply because they removed code. Sometimes code is meaningful, irrelevant noise.

Comment: Ok, I guess there might be cases where it is fine to remove code. However those edits then really need to explain well in the edit comment why code is irrelevant. Otherwise I'd always reject those.